# Why Eclipse duplicate folders and files?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to test Eventuate (framework JAVA that implement event sourcing) But  I have a huge feature with eclipse, when I imported the project eclipse display the same files a lot of time.

For information the project is a spring-boot project using gradle.

This is a screen shot:

[image]

Would do you have an idea why this happens ?

Comment: its an Eclipse feature.. The package view and directories is being displayed in your screen shot. There is little arrow pointing down in the package explorer tab on the left if you click that you can set filters and display less or more as you wish

Comment: it's a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486867 related to the chosen Package Presentation setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Package Explorer instead of the Project Explorer, and you won't get the second duplicate.